# Find closest distance every day in two datasets

Tags: qgis, distance-matrix

My friend and I want to use our exported Google Location data to see how close we've been, at the same time, before becoming friends.

In other words: I have two datasets of timestamped coordinates, spanning ≈3 years and ≈50 000 points each. I want to calculate the nearest distance between two points *on the same day or hour*.

I have figured out how to find closest neighbors and do distance matrices, but only for the entire dataset. I am looking maybe for some way of "stepping through" my datasets, day by day or hour by hour, and re-doing the distance matrix calculation.

Is this possible in QGIS?

Comment: I second @BERA, this would be more approachable programmatically and python has great tools. Can you share any sample data?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a virtual layer. I calculated a string column from my date column as year-month-day_hour, for example 2008-12-19_17 then join the two layers using this column.

So each point from layer 1 is joined to all other points in layer 2. Then select unique point 1 id that has the minimum distance to a point 2.

The virtual layer will probably be very slow so right-click and export it to for example a shapefile.

```sql
with cte as (
    select  loc1.id as id1, 
            loc1.date as date1, 
            loc1.geometry as geometry, 
            loc2.id as id2, 
            loc2.date as date2, 
            st_distance(loc1.geometry, loc2.geometry) as distance
    from loc1
    join loc2
    on loc1.date=loc2.date
    where loc1.id<loc2.id
            )
select id1, date1, geometry, id2, date2, min(distance) as distance from cte
group by id1
```

For example both 6269 and 9233 in layer 1 are closest to 12425 in layer 2:
[image]